# Как проверить не из-за отсутствия ли интернета произошла ошибка с запросом, используя Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Использую Alamofire таким образом:

```
func requestNews(page: Int = 0, completion: @escaping Success) {

    // url = ... , headers = ...

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: headers).responseJSON() { response in

         // нет интернета? ошибка сервера? или все в порядке?

    }
}
```

Каким образом внутри метода можно понять, что ошибка связана именно с недоступностью интернета?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал метод таким образом:

```
typealias StateWithError = (_ success: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> ()

class ApiManager: NSObject {

    public func requestNews(page: Int = 0, completion: @escaping StateWithError) {

        let url = "www.example.com/news/"
        let headers = authBacicHeader()

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: headers).responseJSON() { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:

                // если все ок - парсим данные ...

                completion(true, nil)

            case .failure(let error):
                completion(false, error) // если не ок - вернем ошибку
            }
        }
    }

    // ... так же добавил пару статических методов:

    // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nserror/1448136-nserror_codes

    static func isErrorNoInternetOrSlowInternet(_ error: Error) -> Bool {
        if let err = error as? URLError {
            if err.code == .notConnectedToInternet || err.code == .cannotConnectToHost { // NOTE: no internet
                return true
            }
            if err.code == .networkConnectionLost || err.code == .timedOut { // NOTE: slow internet
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    static func isErrorServerDown(_ error: Error) -> Bool {
        if let err = error as? URLError {
            if err.code == .badServerResponse || err.code == .cannotFindHost {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Теперь в вызывающем коде можно сделать, например, так:

```
ApiManager.shared.requestNews { success, error  in
    if success {

        // показываем новости

    } else {

        // обрабатываем ошибку

        if let error = error {
            if ApiManager.isErrorNoInternetOrSlowInternet(error) {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Отсутствует Интернет", message: "Нет подключения к интернет или интернет слишком медленный", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                return alert
            }
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно смотреть ошибку response.result.error или сделать валидацию ответного кода http:

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
  .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
  .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
  .response { response in
  // response handling code
}
```